# SVN+SSH file permissions and login

Tags: linux, svn

Can't seem to log into the Tortoise Repository Browser or make any write changes locally. Only read access works.

Our RHEL 6.5 linux box has subversion installed. Our svnserve.conf is configured as such:

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

Our subversion repo is located at /data/svn/repo. Its user/group is subversion:subversion.

The linux users all have SSH keys to log onto the box. We can all read from the repo, we just can't make any changes. The error we get is

```
data/svn/repo/format - file permission denied
```

1. How can we setup svn+ssh:// from a local machine onto the subversion server. We are using TurtoiseSVN. I tried svn+ssh://HOSTNAME/data/svn/repos and gives the same file permission denied error.
2. How can we commit changes locally when logged onto the server itself.

I've tried setting it up according to this article but it doesn't seem to work or I'm not understanding it properly: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth

Note: We are not using Apache to host it nor do we wish to.

Update: Adding the group subversion to each linux user and chmod the directory svn to 770 has solved some of my issues. Users are able to connect via the SVN windows browser by using svn+ssh://username@hostname/path/to/repo

However, users are unable to commit locally on the linux server.

Comment: Look at your filesystem permissions on the SVN repository.  Does everyone have read/write access to the files in the repository?  Filesystem access happens as the user.

Comment: I ended up doing a chmod 770 on the svn folder and adding the group subversion as a secondary group to all users requiring access. Now users can checkout and commit files from the TortoiseSVN app on Windows 7. However, they are able to checkout but not commit when logged on the linux box locally.